# Counting form fields using js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the form that looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="">
   <label for="id_count-count">Count:</label>
   <input id="id_count-count" type="number" name="count-count">
   <div class="extrafieldWrapper"></div>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Depending on number of field `count` i add or delete new couple of fields `item` and `item2`. For example: if value of field `count` will be 2, it will generate two couples of fields `item` and `item2`.

There is this fields:

```
<label for="id_items-0-item">Item:</label>
<input id="id_items-0-item" type="number" name="items-0-item">
<label for="id_items-0-item2">Item2:</label>
<input id="id_items-0-item2" class="children_age" type="number" name="items-0-item2" value="0">
<div class="extrafieldWrapperChAge"></div>
```

Then, depending on each value of field `item2` i add new fields that calls `childrenage`. There is how looks `childrenage` field:

```
<label for="id_childrenage-0-childrenage">ChildrenAge 1</label>
<input id="id_childrenage-0-childrenage" type="number" name="childrenage-0-childrenage" value="0">
```

Here is fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/79gt20q3/3/) .
And here is imgur of what i want and what i've got [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGV91.jpg).

Depending of value of `item2` the id of `childrenage` is changing too. For example if i have '3' as value of `item2`, then i have `id_childrenage-0-childrenage`, `id_childrenage-1-childrenage` and `id_childrenage-2-childrenage`. And if i have several `item2` i have new examples of `childrenage` that count their id from the start for each `item2`:

```
<label for="id_items-0-item2">Item2:</label>
<input id="id_items-0-item2" class="children_age" type="number" name="items-0-item2" value="2">
<div class="extrafieldWrapperChAge">
   <label for="id_childrenage-0-childrenage">ChildrenAge</label>
   <input id="id_childrenage-0-childrenage" type="number" name="childrenage-0-childrenage" value="0">
   <label for="id_childrenage-1-childrenage">ChildrenAge</label>
   <input id="id_childrenage-1-childrenage" type="number" name="childrenage-1-childrenage" value="0">
</div>
<label for="id_items-0-item2">Item2:</label>
<input id="id_items-0-item2" class="children_age" type="number" name="items-0-item2" value="1">
<div class="extrafieldWrapperChAge">
   <label for="id_childrenage-0-childrenage">ChildrenAge</label>
   <input id="id_childrenage-0-childrenage" type="number" name="childrenage-0-childrenage" value="0">
</div>
```

In example above i have 2 fields `item2`, on one of it value '2' and on another value '1'. According to this i have two fields of `childrenage` for the first `item2` with id `id_childrenage-0-childrenage` and `id_childrenage-1-childrenage`, and one field `childrenage` for the second with id `id_childrenage-0-childrenage`. But i need that count of id `childrenage` go on from the first `item2` to the last, this is example:

```
<label for="id_items-0-item2">Item2:</label>
<input id="id_items-0-item2" class="children_age" type="number" name="items-0-item2" value="2">
<div class="extrafieldWrapperChAge">
   <label for="id_childrenage-0-childrenage">ChildrenAge</label>
   <input id="id_childrenage-0-childrenage" type="number" name="childrenage-0-childrenage" value="0">
   <label for="id_childrenage-1-childrenage">ChildrenAge</label>
   <input id="id_childrenage-1-childrenage" type="number" name="childrenage-1-childrenage" value="0">
</div>
<label for="id_items-0-item2">Item2:</label>
<input id="id_items-0-item2" class="children_age" type="number" name="items-0-item2" value="1">
<div class="extrafieldWrapperChAge">
   <label for="id_childrenage-2-childrenage">ChildrenAge</label>
   <input id="id_childrenage-2-childrenage" type="number" name="childrenage-2-childrenage" value="0">
</div>
```

Here is js code that realize this:

```
$(function(){
   $('#id_count-count').on('change', function(e){
      var n = $('#id_count-count').val() || 0;
      var html = "<input id='id_items-TOTAL_FORMS' type='hidden' value='" + n + "' name='items-TOTAL_FORMS'>"
         + "<input id='id_items-INITIAL_FORMS' type='hidden' value='0' name='items-INITIAL_FORMS'>"
         + "<input id='id_items-MIN_NUM_FORMS' type='hidden' value='0' name='items-MIN_NUM_FORMS'>"
         + "<input id='id_items-MAX_NUM_FORMS' type='hidden' value='15' name='items-MAX_NUM_FORMS'>";

      for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         html += "<div>Items" + (i + 1) + "</div>"
            + "<br/><label for='id_items-" + i + "-item'>Item:</label>"
            + "<input id='id_items-" + i + "-item' type='number' name='items-" + i + "-item'/>"
            + "<label for='id_items-" + i + "-item2'>Item2:</label>"
            + "<input id='id_items-" + i + "-item2' type='number' value='0' name='items-" + i + "-item2' class='children_age'/>"
            + "<div class='extrafieldWrapperChAge'></div>";
      }
      $(".extrafieldWrapper").html(html);
   });
   $(".extrafieldWrapper").on('change', '.children_age', function(e){
      var n = $(this).val() || 0;
      var html = "<input id='id_childrenage-TOTAL_FORMS' type='hidden' value='" + n + "' name='childrenage-TOTAL_FORMS'>"
         + "<input id='id_childrenage-INITIAL_FORMS' type='hidden' value='0' name='childrenage-INITIAL_FORMS'>"
         + "<input id='id_childrenage-MIN_NUM_FORMS' type='hidden' value='0' name='childrenage-MIN_NUM_FORMS'>"
         + "<input id='id_childrenage-MAX_NUM_FORMS' type='hidden' value='15' name='childrenage-MAX_NUM_FORMS'>"; 

      for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         html += "<br/><label for='id_childrenage-" + i + "-childrenage'>ChildrenAge "+(i+1)+"</label>"
            + "<input id='id_childrenage-" + i + "-childrenage' type='number' value='0' name='childrenage-" + i + "-childrenage' />";
      }
      $(this).next('.extrafieldWrapperChAge').html(html);
   });

});
```

Hope you you understand what i mean.
I am newbie in java-script, can you help me to write the code in the right way. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is simply my personal opinion but *holy crap* that is a lot of text. Let's see if we can clarify a few things: **1** what do you start with? **2** given very explicit instructions, what do you end up with? **3** could you *possibly* add your code to the snippet editor, JsFiddle, or Codepen with a working example of what you've got?

Comment: I'm already edit the post and add JsFiddle. Sorry, but i don't know how to do text smaller.

Comment: so what is your end goal -- what goal are you looking to accomplish here

Comment: A add new imgur link of what i have and what  need, it is a simple example.

Comment: Okay. I think I have a bit more of an idea as to what you want in particular. Give me a minute. I'm going to attempt to clean up your code (It's a little messy for my tastes and it is making it hard to read)

Comment: Thank you, @Jhecht

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular answer was getting needlessly long, so I've decided to truncate it to just the current answer.

## The Code

```js
$(function() {
  var fieldset = $('<fieldset>');
  var legend = $('<legend>');
  var input = $('<input>').prop('type', 'number');
  var hidden = $('<input>').prop('type', 'hidden');
  var label = $('<label>');
  var child_wrapper = $('<div class="child-wrapper">');
  /*
    Here we create a couple of new HTML elements. These elements are not a part of the 
    HTML DOM yet and can therefore be manipulated without any visual changes.
  */
  var create_hidden_fields = function(str, fields_arr) {
    var ret = [];
    //return array;
    $.each(fields_arr, function(i, obj) {
      //Loops through each field to set up the hidden values
      var h = hidden.clone();
      //Clones the hidden fields
      h.prop('id', 'id_' + str + '-' + obj.name).prop('name', str + '-' + obj.name).val(obj.value);
      //Sets the ID, name, and value.
      ret.push(h);
    });
    return ret;
  };

  $('#id_count-count').on('change', function(e) {
    var n = $(this).val() || 0;
    //Gets the id count value, or 0;

    var hidden_fields = [{
      name: 'TOTAL_FORMS',
      value: n
    }, {
      name: 'INITIAL_FORMS',
      value: 0
    }, {
      name: 'MIN_NUM_FORMS',
      value: 0
    }, {
      name: 'MAX_NUM_FORMS',
      value: 15
    }];
    //Hidden fields pre-build, makes life easier, since there seems to be a pattern

    var h_arr = create_hidden_fields('items', hidden_fields);
    //Hidden Array created
    if ($(this.form).children(':hidden')) {
      $(this.form).children(':hidden').remove();
      //Removes all the current hidden fields, because lazy.
    }
    $(this.form).prepend(h_arr); //adds in our created hidden fields.

    var form = $(this.form).children('.extra-field-wrapper');
    //Gets the fieldset wrapper.
    form.empty();
    //Empties any children there already. Otherwise extra children are added.

    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      var fs_clone = fieldset.clone(); //clones the fieldset element
      var l_clone = legend.clone().text("Item " + (i + 1));
      // clones the legend element and adds text
      var la_clone_1 = label.clone();
      //label clone 1
      var input_clone_1 = input.clone();
      //Input clone 1
      var child_wrapper_clone = child_wrapper.clone().prop('id', 'parent-' + (1 + i));
      //We use clones to keep our initial values safe. This way we can alter the clones without changing our defaults

      fs_clone.append(l_clone);
      //Adds our legend up top for readability;      
      la_clone_1.prop('for', 'id-items-' + i + '-item').html('Parent ' + (i + 1));
      //Adds the 'for' property with the correct ID, then sets the HTML. Item and Item2 were getting confusing
      input_clone_1.prop('value', 0).prop('id', 'id-items-' + i + '-item');
      //Sets the default value to 0, and the necessary ID for our label to work
      var la_clone_2 = label.clone().html('# of Children').prop('for', 'id-items-' + i + '-num-children');
      /*
       This is a lot in one line, it clones the label element, adds the HTML, and sets the property all in one.
      */
      var input_clone_2 = input.clone().prop('id', 'id-items-' + i + '-num-children').prop('value', 0).addClass('children_age');
      //See above comment. One difference is that this adds our class for our next function to work

      fs_clone.append([la_clone_1, input_clone_1, la_clone_2, input_clone_2, child_wrapper_clone]);
      //This could probably be cleaned up, but for now it works.

      form.append(fs_clone); //adds the fieldset clone to the form.
    } //End for

  });

  $(".extra-field-wrapper").on('change', '.children_age', function(e) {

    var n = $(this).val() || 0;
    // the current value of the item
    var append_array = [];
    //Add an HTML append array, lessens calls to the $(this).next().append();

    $(this).before(h_arr);
    //Adds the hidden elements before this element

    $(this).next('.child-wrapper').empty();
    //Clears the child elements

    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      var l_clone = label.clone().html('Children Age' + (i + 1));
      var i_clone = input.clone().addClass('child-age').prop('value', 0);

      append_array.push(l_clone);
      append_array.push(i_clone);
      //Adds the elements to the append_array since we are now done with them.
    }

    $(this).next('.child-wrapper').append(append_array);
    //Adds all created elements;

    var children_age = $('input.child-age').each(function(i, el) {
      var self = $(el);
      //Lazy handle
      var label = $(el).prev();
      //The label is the element in front of our current element.
      label.text("Child Age " + (i + 1)).prop('for', 'id_childrenage_' + i + '_childrenage');
      //Gives correct label number /re does the for property;
      self.prop('id', 'id_childrenage_' + i + '_childrenage');
      //give correct id now that changes have been made to the dom.
    });


    var hidden_fields = [{
      name: 'TOTAL_FORMS',
      value: children_age.length
    }, {
      name: 'INITIAL_FORMS',
      value: 0
    }, {
      name: 'MIN_NUM_FORMS',
      value: 0
    }, {
      name: 'MAX_NUM_FORMS',
      value: 15
    }];
    //We have to redeclare this function here in order for the value: n  to work correctly.
    if ($('#id_childrenage-TOTAL_FORMS').length == 0) {
      //This element does not exist yet in the DOM
      var hidden_fields = [{
        name: 'TOTAL_FORMS',
        value: children_age.length
      }, {
        name: 'INITIAL_FORMS',
        value: 0
      }, {
        name: 'MIN_NUM_FORMS',
        value: 0
      }, {
        name: 'MAX_NUM_FORMS',
        value: 15
      }];
      //We have to redeclare this function here in order for the value: n  to work correctly.

      var h_arr = create_hidden_fields('childrenage', hidden_fields);
      //creates the hidden fields
      $(this.form).prepend(h_arr);
    } else {
      $('#id_childrenage-TOTAL_FORMS').val(children_age.length);
    }


  });

});
```

```css
label {
  font-weight: 800;
}
input[type="number"] {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="">
  <label for="id_count-count">Count:</label>
  <input id="id_count-count" type="number" name="count-count">
  <div class="extra-field-wrapper"></div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

## The Explanation

I did a few things here, and there is more than likely a better way, but I did the best with my own time constraints.

1. I create the items to copy into the with jQuery because I'm old school and I just do not remember anything about how the `template` tag works so I stay away from it's particular variety of magics. The fieldset and legend are there *solely* for readability. In your actual code you can just delete their references as well as `fs_clone` and `l_clone`, instead attach the items directly to the form element.
2. I created a function that exists solely within the realm of our wrapping anonymous function called `create_hidden_fields`, as a programmer, mathematician, and all around lazy person I noticed the pattern in the naming convention and this appealed to me more than having to create and copy a bunch of items by hand ***every*** time I wanted to create a field.
3. I have the `id_childrenage-TOTAL_FORMS` (which is, by the way, the *weirdest* naming convention I've ever come across) to the `form` itself. Since we don't need more than 1 copy of the input.
4. The reason the `hidden_fields` array is redeclared in both functions is fairly simple: if it is declared before the variable `n` is, the `TOTAL_FORMS` input won't have the correct value. Not good.
5. Hopefully everything else can be answered by my comments in the code itself.

Happy Coding.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it works very fine! But I have two remarks, I need to count `id-items-n-item`, `id-items-n-num-children` and `id_childrenage_n_childrenage` from '0'. And second i need to have `<input id='id_items-TOTAL_FORMS' type='hidden' value='" + n + "' name='items-TOTAL_FORMS'>` where `n` is number of filled forms(parents and children), and <input id='id_items-TOTAL_FORMS' type='hidden' value='" + n + "' name='childrenage-TOTAL_FORMS'>, where n is number of filled childrenage fields. Its for my django framework. Sory for my pure js. And thank you once again

Comment: I've never used Django, but I must say that seems like a real pain to have to do that.

Comment: I've made an edit @ZagorodniyOlexiy, let me know if that helps you out. I'd be lying if I said I totally understood what all of this was for.

Comment: Thank you very @Jhecht it works very fine! I'm very Thakfull to you!

Comment: i'm sorry that disturbing you. But i found the bug can you help me with it? `<input id='id_items-TOTAL_FORMS' type='hidden' value='" + n + "' name='items-TOTAL_FORMS'>` need to count how many couples of Parent and Children(only couples! without `childrenage`), and `<input id='id_items-TOTAL_FORMS' type='hidden' value='" + n + "' name='childrenage-TOTAL_FORMS'>` needs to count a sum of all Childrenage fields. Sorry very much! And thak you once again

Comment: So, the `id_items-TOTAL_FORMS` needs to count how many *couples* of parent and children? So the two forms that get populated originally, before we've added the children age form elements?

Comment: Yes. `id_items-TOTAL_FORMS` need to count just couples of parent and children. Like on this example https://jsfiddle.net/79gt20q3/3/ . Thank you very much

Comment: and is `id_childrenage-TOTAL_FORMS` supposed to give you the ***total*** amount of children age inputs, or just the ones for that ***specific*** wrapper?

Comment: just to confirm, in [this image](http://imgur.com/hpqZkVB), would `id_items-TOTAL_FORMS` be 3 or 6? and would `id_childrenage-TOTAL_COUNT` be 10?

Comment: yes, `id_items-TOTAL_FORMS` = 3, `id_childrenage-TOTAL_FORMS` = 10

Comment: Okay. Give me a second.

Comment: Yessss! It works! Thank you very much! If you will need help in django i will be glad to help you! Thanks once again!